# Change the origin coordinates in GIMP

Tags: coordinates, gimp

In the GIMP image editor, as with many other computer graphics, the origin coordinates (0,0) are in the upper left corner of the image. I'm doing work with PDF documents which go by the mathematical origin of (0,0) being in the lower left corner.

I'd like to flip the y-axis ruler in the gimp so that the origin is in the lower left corner. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this, but by flipping my image vertically the rulers are correct (even if it looks odd).